# Currently getting a segmentation fault: 11 and I am unsure why?

Tags: c, debugging, segmentation-fault

If you want to see the code, I'll leave it below, but what I really want is directions on how to use debugger with multiple source files. So I have: 
main.c, slides.c, and header.h
I know to use: gcc -g -Wall main.c slide.c header.h
,but after that I am unsure where to go. Could anyone direct me on the next step. Without the call to the method in the slides.c program there seems to be no segment fault, but once it is called it happens.
If you want to look at the code this is it:

**main.c**

```
    #define EXTERN
    #include "header.h"
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

        int N; 
        //int oddsonly = (BITS_PER_SEG*2) - 1; 
        int NSegs;
        int numOfPrimes;

        if (argc == 2) sscanf(argv[1],"%d",&N);
            else scanf("%d",&N);
            NSegs = (int)ceil(  ((N-3 )/(float)odds_only)  );
            printf("This is the number of segments made: %d\n", NSegs);
        //this is how we make a doubly linked list 
        //void makelinkedlist(){
        //this is how we make a doubly linked list 
        //void makelinkedlist(){
        int i; 
        seg *node; 
        seg *current;
        //head = (seg*)malloc(sizeof(seg));
        head = NULL;
        for(i = 0; i < NSegs; i++ ) { 
            if(i == 1) {
                node = malloc(sizeof(seg)); 
                node->prev = NULL; 
                node->next = NULL;
                head = node;
            }//if
            else{
                current = malloc(sizeof(seg)); 
                current = head; 
                while(current->next != NULL){
                    current = current->next; 
                }//while
                current->next = malloc(sizeof(seg)); 
                node = current->next; 
                node->prev = current; 
                node->next = NULL; 
                //head = head;   
                }//else
            }//for


       printf("Done allocating %d nodes\n",i);  


       sieveOfE( N );    // Modify my solution in C project 1 !!!

       numOfPrimes = countPrimes( N );

       printf("Number of primes found = %d\n", numOfPrimes );
```

**slides.c problem area**

```
void setBit(int nthoddnumber){
    printf("this is the first method sieveOfE calls\n");
    seg *temp = head;

    int segmentnumber = nthoddnumber/BITS_PER_SEG; //gives you the segment number
    int posbit = nthoddnumber- (segmentnumber * BITS_PER_SEG); 
    int finalbitpos = posbit%32;//this is the bit postion in the
    int i = posbit/32;//integer array position
    int j;
    for(j = 0; j < segmentnumber; j++) {//iterating through Linked list
        temp = temp->next;

    }

    //something is happening here 
    temp->bits[i] |= 1 <<(finalbitpos);   
    //nothing prints past here 
    //head = head;

}
```

Comment: Why assign `current` twice?  `current = malloc(sizeof(seg)); current = head;`

Comment: so the malloc is useless right? I removed it and finally figured out debugger and I am receiving a stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x400)
for this line:-> 36      while(current->next != NULL){

Comment: Do you know why this would happen. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You want to run `gcc -g -Wall -o slides slides.c main.c`, then run `lldb` on `./slides`.  You can set a breakpoint on a function with `breakpoint set -n sieveOfE` or on a line with `breakpoint set -f slides.c -l 50`.  Please look up a `lldb` tutorial.

In `gdb`, you can instead use either a function name as a breakpoint (`break sieveOfE`) or a line number like `break slides.c:50`, and run.

Comment: So I not allowed to use gdb -- I'm on a Mac -- but I am allowed to use lldb and I entered what you said, but receive: break sieveOfE
invalid command 'breakpoint sieveOfE'

Comment: Added `lldb` instructions, but see a tutorial.